# How to use html tags in setText of android with parameters?

Tags: android, html, json, textview

i ahve seen the use of html tags in  setText .But in my application i ahve a parameter returnString which stores the resultant string.How i can apply Html tags for returnString in setText(retunstring)?
   Hers the code.

```
       try{
         returnString = "";
       JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
         for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                 JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 Log.i("log_tag","name: "+json_data.getString("name")

                 );
                 //Get an output to the screen

                 returnString += "\n" +"Name:"+ json_data.getString("name")+json_data.getString("address")+"\n"+json_data.getString("phone")+"\n";
                 TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resu);

                 tv1.setText(returnString);   //<----How do i use html tags here

                 tv1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

         }
   }
  catch(JSONException e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());

  }
```

Comment: you mean you want newline between name,address and phone?

Comment: no..i just want to style name adres and phone

Answer (score 0):

Use `Html.fromHtml("your_html_here")` inside `setText`.

Example:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#ffffff> hello </font>"));
```

Comment: No this im familar with it...i jsut want to add html format to textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(returnString)); i cant use this bcuse returnString is not in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(returnString));
```

Comment: I found a solution.
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#ffffff>" +returnString+ "</font>"));